# Wicket:PleaseWaitBehavior-Showing, "Loading X of Y"

Tags: java, ajax, wicket

I'm trying to show a loading message that tells the user how far along they are in the loading process after they hit submit. The problem is, the loading bar shows up, but it shows "Loading 0 of 0", until the process finishes.

```
 private AjaxButton createSubmit() {
        Submit = new AjaxButton("Submit",new Model<String>()) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 202575339939441557L;

        @Override
          public void onSubmit(final AjaxRequestTarget target,
              final Form<?> form) {
            handleSubmit(target);
          }
        };
        Submit.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        Submit.add(new PleaseWaitBehavior(new Model<String>(
            "Processing Message " +  loadingNumber + " of " + size)));
        return Submit;
      }
```

This is the class that handles the submit behavior. I change both numbers from 0 in the handleSubmit(target) method and iterate LoadingNumber inside a for loop in that class. The change is never reflected in the message and I have tried removing and adding back in the PleaseWaitBehavior. I am completely stumped. Does Wicket just not allow what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Submit.add(new PleaseWaitBehavior(new Model<String>(
        "Processing Message " +  loadingNumber + " of " + size)));
```

I hope you realize that here you concatenate a String that is used later in the UI. There is no code that will re-calculate this again and construct a new String for the UI.

Please read about static versus dynamic models in Wicket at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Working+with+Wicket+models.

For your task you need to use Ajax calls to ask the server about the progress and to repaint the message.
Here is an article that explains the problem and provides a sample solution - http://wicketinaction.com/2014/07/working-with-background-jobs/

Comment: I'd like to thank you for showing me that page about models. I am now using CompoundPropertyModels so I'm no longer static.  But to be quite honest (Being a complete rookie at wicket and using java for less than a year), I don't understand what I was supposed to take away from the wicketinAction. I've looked over it multiple times but it's going over my head, and the pleasewaitbehavior still does not iterate.

Comment: The easiest approach is to show a panel with "Loading" indicator and this panel to have AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior that asks the server side whether the operation has finished. Once it is finished then hide/close this panel.